# Twitter API shorten [created_at]

Tags: php, api, date, twitter, time

I'm using the Twitter API and am rather new to it. I understand that when I use the GET tweet array `[created_at]` it outputs something along the lines of

> Thu Aug 31 12:07:00 +0000 2017

is there a way to simply get

> Thu Aug 31

in one variable and

> 12:07:00

in a second variable? So I can simply use just the time and date.

Comment: Have you googled on 'how to parse datetime in php'?
Here's what I've got as at top of results: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first convert that string into date and time formate by passing that value in date() function from php.

Then you can get date and time from that and store that in different variables.

**Use date and time format function from php.**

```
<?php

   $dateandtime = new DateTime("Your date string getting from twitter");
   $variable1=$dateandtime->format("D M m");        
   $variable2=$dateandtime->format("H:i:s");

 ?>
```

Comment: It should be `d` instead of `m` in `$variable1`

Answer (score 0):

Another core approach to convert returned datetime in the required format

```
$dateString = "Thu Aug 31 12:07:00 +0000 2017";
//use strtotime function to get timestamp of a string date
//returnedTimestamp=strtotime($dateString);
$datePart=date('D M d',$returnedTimestamp);
$timePart=date('H:i:s',$returnedTimestamp);
```